# Robustness in my XML-RPC plugin

Tags: xml-rpc, theory, robustness

I have written a jQuery plugin that makes communicating with XML-RPC servers from client side JavaScript much easier than it would otherwise be. I have used it in an application of my own where is successfully communicates with an rtorrent client. I published it as a stand alone plugin: [jquery-xmlrpc](https://github.com/maelstrom/jquery-xmlrpc/)

A user has made logged two issues ([#1](https://github.com/maelstrom/jquery-xmlrpc/issues/1) and [#2](https://github.com/maelstrom/jquery-xmlrpc/pull/2)) against the plugin, stating that it fails to parse invalid XML-RPC. The invalid XML-RPC in question is empty `<value>` nodes. The user is dealing with an XML-RPC server that is sending invalid XML-RPC documents. Consider the following XML-RPC document, containing a `<nil>`, empty string, and an incorrect empty `<value>` node:

```
<struct>
    <member>
        <!-- A null value -->
        <name>nilElement</name>
        <value><nil /></value>
    </member>
    <member>
        <!-- An empty string -->
        <name>emptyString</name>
        <value><string></string></value>
    </member>
    <member>
        <!-- Invalid XML-RPC -->
        <name>badEmptyValue</name>
        <value></value>
    </member>
</struct>
```

Initially, I was happy to handle incorrectly empty `<value>` nodes, and treat them as `<nil/>`/null elements. This seemed an odd corner case, but one that was easy to handle, and kept within the spirit of the Robustness Principal:

> "Be liberal in what you accept, and
> conservative in what you send"
>
> > [RFC 1122](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1122#page-12)

But then the issue was updated to say that the badly behaving server also sent raw strings in `<value>` nodes, as follows:

```
<!-- Correct string encoding -->
<value><string>Hello, World!</string></value>

<!-- Incorrect string encoding -->
<value>Raw, incorrect string</value>
```

At this point, the remote server is just plain incorrect. This is not valid XML-RPC at all. But the Robustness Principal states that I should be liberal in what I accept.

How far should the Robustness Principal be taken? Should I accept raw strings? Should I refuse, telling the other user to log a bug against the badly behaving XML-RPC server? At which point does accepting bad input go too far?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, XML-RPC spec says that `<value>` nodes with no child elements should be treated as string nodes. I must have missed that section. The correct answer in this case is to conform to the spec and correctly handle strings in `<value>` nodes.